# Can each handler handle the request in Chain of Responsibility Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Here I am not going to re mentioned about the Chain of Responsibility (CoR) pattern definitions. However what I want to know is that, if there is a series of handlers in a chain, and if a request is handled by all handlers and the last handlers will not process the request if the beginning handlers are failed, is it against the pattern ?

I will explain with an example. Assume an online application which allows users to search books. When user submits a request, the system does the search and shows results. Assume, this functionality is implemented in a CoR pattern.

First handler takes the request parameters (book category, price,author etc), and adds additional parameters (such as users country,region,language which are picked from request) and does certain validations.
The second handler takes the output of first handler and look in the database and create a list of results. Those results are transferred into a third handler.  Third handler will order the results, filter, change language. If any of preceding handler is failed, the following handlers will not do their job.

Is the usage of CoR against its concepts ? or any other good pattern for this ?

Comment: This sounds like [pipe-and-filter](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/pipe_and_filter.html) rather than Chain of Responsibility. If the design fits your need, don't worry about "violating" CoR. Patterns are tools to solve a problem; you're not supposed to change your problem to fit the tool. CoR's [problem](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398601): `Avoid coupling the sender of a request to its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. Chain the receiving objects and pass the request along the chain until an object handles it.`

Answer (score 4):

Chain of Responsibility generally has only one handler take care of a request.

A great analogy is from the 1970's [Classic Tootsie Roll Commercial - "How Many Licks"](http://youtu.be/O6rHeD5x2tI) where a boy (the request) tries to get the answer to the question of "How many licks does it take to get to the center of a Tootsie Pop?"

He goes to the first animal, who doesn't know the answer, but who sends him to the next animal, etc. Finally, the "request" is processed and the boy gets his answer.

Only the start of the chain is known by the boy (all the other animal references are given sequentially).

In your problem, it seems you have a well defined (static) order of processing. Unless you need to swap the steps in and out dynamically, or reuse steps in other projects, there's nothing wrong with a simple, modular pattern: It's called Keep it simple stupid - KISS.

Answer (score 2):

If a filter is functionally dependant on another (i.e. expects something to be happened before its execution) then these two functions should be executed within the scope of the same filter. The main logic about COR is its *modularity*, in other words the fact that you can add/remove filters at will without affecting the flow of the data in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of CoR is that each chain handler is unaware of the chain (only his successor to delegate the request if it could not handle it) and as you base your chain elements on each other you violate a core concept of CoR in my eyes - I would prefer using a Decorator to decorate your originating object with additional data using the originating object - in your example, you would have a request parameter object, then a result object which decorates the request parameter object with the results of this request and afterwards a third object decorating the results with ordering, filtering and/or changing the language.

Comment: Decorator would only seem right to me if handlers "wrapped" each other and needed to be added/removed dynamically at runtime.